# Building and Deploying ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have a MVC web application that I have just made in visual studio 2013 and I am looking for help on deploying it to a server and running it. I have published the file to a local directory via Visual studio and then moved the file contents to the IIS server, yet this is where problems arise.

I am unable to launch the application and I am not sure what needs to be done to make this happen. I tried looking at virtual directories, but I can't directly modify the server, only to the point of adding/removing files (I'm putting this on one of my school's servers.)

Could someone point me in the right direction of what needs to be done to set this up and have it working?

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, you are unable to launch. did you get any error when you launch the application? what happen when you browse you home page?

Comment: I'm rather lost in what I need to do. I deployed the contents locally and then moved them to the server and tried to load /Home/Index/. I have no access to an IIS manager or anything. So at this point I'm rather lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be configured as an application in IIS. As far as I'm aware, there are no workarounds. ASP.NET handler needs to be invoked from IIS.

Comment: So if I don't have access to the server then no luck? Would I be better of porting it to a website and then trying that or would I run into the same problems?

Comment: I believe the issue would be the same

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps of publishing application in IIS:
http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/host-asp-net-web-api-in-iis-using-visual-studio-publish.aspx